# Sums of primes that are themselves prime

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

I'm not a math expert so this may be a trivial question;  if $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime, let:

$$S(n) = \sum_{i=1}^n p_i$$

be the sum of the first $n$ primes and

$$P(n) = | \{1 \leq  i \leq n \mid S(i) \mbox{ is prime} \} | $$

be the number of the sums $S(i), 1 \leq i\ \leq n$  that are prime. Do we have

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P(n)}{n} = 0\;?$$

Where can I find a proof?

EDIT: I generated the sequence $P(n)$ and found it on [OEIS: Numbers n such that n is prime and is equal to the sum of the first k primes for some k.](http://oeis.org/A013918), but there is not a lot of information there.

Comment: See also http://oeis.org/A013916 although there is not much information there, either.

Comment: A first step would be to understand how many of the $S(n)$ are multiples of a given number $d$.  Already for $d=3$ I don't know how to determine the number of $S(n)$'s that are multiples of $3$.  Such questions seem too hard to answer (although one can of course formulate conjectures).

Comment: My guess is that this task is just outside of the reach of current technology.  Using the recent results of Maynard, we can find k such that for any admissible tuple $h_1,\ldots,h_k$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $n+h_1,\ldots,n+h_k$ contain at least three primes (say), with no primes between any two of the $n+h_i$.  If we set the $h_i$ to all be multiples of three, this at least shows that $S(i)$ can be divisible by three infinitely often; I believe the argument can be pushed to show that $S(i)$ is divisible by 3 for a set of i of positive density (cont)

Comment: ... which would show that the limsup of P(n)/n is strictly less than 1, but I don't believe that these sorts of arguments are strong enough yet to send P(n)/n to zero.  (But it may be that the situation will improve in a few years, at the current rate of progress on these problems.)  EDIT: Strictly speaking one needs the refinement of Maynard's result established recently by Banks, Freiberg, and Turnage-Butterbaugh.

Comment: @TerryTao:  The sums $S(n)$ alternate in parity.  So $P(n)/n$ is trivially at most $1/2$.  But what you say would apply to maybe get strictly below $1/2$.

Comment: Yes, good point.  If one uses Maynard (and Banks et al.) to ensure at least six primes amongst the $n+h_i$, then we can get S(i) divisible by 3 for infinitely many even i, and so one should indeed be able to get $P(n)/n$ below 1/2 by a modification of this argument (one has to allow the diameter of the admissible tuple to be as large as a small multiple of $\log n$).

Comment: @TerryTao:  I don't understand how one gets a constant below $1/2$ though.  My understanding is that the work of Maynard et al does not yet give positive proportion of tuples.  I.e. how does one get a positive proportion of values for which $S(n)$ is a multiple of $3$?  (Infinitely many is fine, and really goes back to Daniel Shiu.)

Comment: To get positive density, one has to sum over all admissible tuples $(h_1,\ldots,h_k)$ of diameter $c \log n$ for some small $c$.  (A similar trick is used on earlier work of Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.5886 to get small gaps $p_{n+1}-p_n \leq \eta \log p_n$ between primes for a set of n of positive density.)  With tuples this wide, one has to be a little more careful to exclude the possibility that there are primes between two of the $n+h_i$, but this can be done with an upper bound Selberg sieve if c is small enough.

Comment: @TerryTao: I'm not sure I believe this argument.  I think that the Maynard result will show that looking over all admissible tuples with $h_j \le c\log n$, that there are say six primes in a positive density of such tuples.  But that's only on the order of $c^k N$.  But an interval of length $c\log N$ will contain seven primes with probability $c^7$.  So I don't see why the primes produced in Maynard's theorem will be consecutive.  I looked at the Banks et al paper; they use a simple maximality argument to produce consecutive primes, but this works only in a lim inf sense, and not always.

Comment: One has to strengthen the Maynard result first, in the spirit of Pintz's results in http://arxiv.org/abs/1305.6289 (main theorem on page 6) in which not only are (say) six of the $n+h_j$ prime, but the remaining $n+h_i$ are almost prime (no factors less than $x^\varepsilon$ for some small absolute constant $\varepsilon$), and then by an upper bound sieve one can also ensure that there are no primes between any two of the $n+h_i$ without losing much density.  (Actually, one may already be able to do this through modifying Maynard's sieve directly, without a Pintz type result.)

Comment: @TerryTao:  I see now what you have in mind.  That certainly seems plausible.  Thanks!

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/636479/18398

Answer (score 3):

I wonder if for questions of this type, the following probabilistic paradigm is useful:

> Instead of adding *all* prime numbers, let us "flip a coin" and include the next prime number with a fixed probability $0<q<1.$

In other words, what can we say about the distribution of primes in the sequence of sums

$$S_{\xi}(n)=\sum_{i=1}^n \xi_i p_i,$$

where $p_i$ is the $i$th prime and $\{\xi_i\}$ is a sequence of i.i.d. Bernoulli random variables? The asymptotic needs to be a.s. with respect to the Bernoulli measure.

Comment: Some users have commented that this is "not an answer". Indeed, it looks more like a question/tentative suggestion. Maybe it makes sense to make it CW?