# Are prime numbers among sums of prime numbers distributed as $\frac n{2\ln(n)}$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-number-theorem, prime-constellations

Let $(s_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ be defined as follows:
For $n\in\mathbb N$, $s_n:=2+3+5+\cdots+p_n$ is the sum of the first $n$ prime numbers (e.g.: $s_1=2$, $s_2=5$, $s_3=10$, $s_4=17$, $\ldots$).

Let $\pi_\sigma(n):=\#\{s_k\mid k\leq n\text{ and }s_k\text{ is prime}\}$ (e.g. $\pi_\sigma(1)=1$, $\pi_\sigma(2)=2$, $\pi_\sigma(3)=2$, $\pi_\sigma(4)=3$, $\ldots$).

Comparing $\pi_\sigma(n)$ with $\frac{n}{2\ln(n)}$ ($\ln$ may denote the natural logarithm) using computer power I suspect
$$\pi_\sigma(n)\sim\frac{n}{2\ln(n)}.$$

The following picture compares the two functions on the range from 1 to 50.000.000. The blue line is $\pi_\sigma(n)$ and the orange line is $\frac n{2\ln(n)}$.

[[image: Comparison of <span class=]$\pi_\sigma(n)$ and $\frac n{2\ln(n)}$ on the range from 1 to 50.000.000" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bk6Ir.png)

My question is: Is this true? Has there already been research made on this question? Does anyone perhabs has prooven this conjecture already?

Until now, I just came up with heuristic arguments to deduce this formula (see below). But these arguments assume for example prime numbers to be randomly distributed within the natural numbers in such a way, that their stochastic distribution is given by the prime number theorem.

Let $\varepsilon>0$. Then there exists an $N\in\mathbb N$ and an $\varepsilon'>0$ (converging to $0$ iff $\varepsilon$ converges to $0$), such that for every $n\geq N$
$$n^2\sim\sim\sum_{i=1}^ni<s_n<\sum_{i=1}^ni^{1+\varepsilon'}\sim\sim n^{2+\varepsilon},$$

where $\sim\sim$ may denote asymptotic equivalence up to a constant.

Now, let us argue heuristically, assuming the following:

1. The sequence $s_n$ is an increasing random sequence.
2. The "probability" of a random number $k\in\mathbb N$ being prime is given by $\frac k{\ln(k)}-\frac{k-1}{\ln(k-1)}$.

We obtain (all up to $\sim\sim$)
$$\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^2}{\ln(i^2)}-\frac{i^2-1}{\ln(i^2-1)}\right)<\pi_\sigma(n)<\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{i^{2+\varepsilon}}{\ln(i^{2+\varepsilon})}-\frac{i^{2+\varepsilon}-1}{\ln(i^{2+\varepsilon}-1)}\right)$$
and consequently
$$\frac12\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\ln(i)}=\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\ln(i^2)}<\pi_\sigma(n)<\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\ln(i^{2+\varepsilon})}=\frac1{2+\varepsilon}\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\ln(i)}.$$
As $\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{1}{\ln(i)}\sim\int_2^n\frac1{\ln(x)}dx\sim\frac{n}{\ln(n)}$ we conclude
$$\frac{n}{2\ln(n)}<\pi_\sigma(n)<\frac{n}{(2+\varepsilon)\ln(n)}.$$

This is a way to deduce the formular heuristically. However, we assumed the sequence $s_n$ to be an increasing random sequence. Why should not $s_{2n}$ be as well an increasing random sequence? This leads to a problem (thank you for the comments @Brian Hopkins, @Joshua Stucky):

Besides $s_1$, all $s_{2n+1}$ are even and therefore not prime. Hence, if we would count for $\pi_\sigma$ only the odd $s_{2n}$ except every $s_n$ (as so done by the 2018 paper indicated by @Brian Hopkins), it would be asymtotic equivalent to $\frac n{\ln(n)}$ instead. This means, the elements of the sequence $s_{2n}$ are "twice as likely" to be prime as we would expect using the prime number theorem. Why should the heuristic argument (2.) work for the increasing random sequence $s_{n}$, but not for the increasing random sequence $s_{2n}$?

Comment: Related to [this 2014 MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153656/sums-of-primes-that-are-themselves-prime) and [this 2014 MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/636479/conjecture-the-sequence-of-sums-of-all-consecutive-primes-contains-an-infinite) which includes some asymptotics and a reference to a 2018 paper.

Comment: I cannot see the picture.

Comment: @OscarLanzi You can find the picture using the link [https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdDEm.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hdDEm.png). It is the same link as the blue link in the question post "The blue line ...".

Comment: Then don't say "following picture". Say p"picture in the following link". Should post the picture anyway in case the link dies.

Comment: @OscarLanzi Thank you for your hint! I am a newbie here on MathOverflow - this is my first question.

Comment: @BrianHopkins Thank you very much for your interesting findings of related questions. Within the next days I will go through them and especially through the 2018 paper to learn about the heuristic ideas this paper contains.

Comment: Half of the $s_n$ are obviously not prime, since every other $s_n$ is even. The other elements of the sequence behave (at least heuristically) like a random sequence of integers, and so the primes distribute among these remaining integers in their usual fashion. As to whether this is known, I don't think so, and I suspect it would be highly nontrivial to prove.

Comment: @JoshuaStucky Thank you very much for your remark. I am not sure, if I understood you correctly. As $s_n$ grows more or less like $n^2$, the "probability" (heuristic argument!) of $s_n$ being prime would be around $\frac{n^2}{\ln(n^2)}-\frac{n^2-1}{\ln(n^2-1)}$ (prime number theorem). We can then of course remove the $s_{2n-1}$ (the even numbers). Wouldn' t we obtain the $s_{2n}$ to be twice as "likely" to be prime than "normal" random numbers of the same size?